# Multi Monitors on Windows 8.1 always revert from Extend to Mirroring after sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, sleep, taskbar, windows-8.1

I run into this issue daily. It seems everytime my computer wakes from sleep the external monitor is "Mirroring" the main display rather than "Extending" it.

Also the setting "Show taskbar buttons on: taskbar where window is open" for the taskbar keeps reverting to the default as well.

I'm using windows 8.1 but it has always been an issue.

Comment: I personally don't have this problem. Please provide more information about your system by updating the question itself.  I updated the tag and title to better reflect the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem: I have the internal screen of the laptop and an outside monitor connected via HDMI cable. Before sleeping I see image in both, and after waking there is only image on the external one. In the control panel the "Multiple Displays" combobox changed its value from "Extend these displays" to "Show only on desktop 2"